# Maximum number of circles inside a given circle

Tags: geometry

The problem is that how to find the maximum number of circles of radius r that can FIT inside a circle of radius R.
where R>r
Example:for r=1 units and R=1.5  units,the answer is 1

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle, https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/smaller-circles-in-larger-circle-d_1849.html

Comment: Thnx for the websites but if you could give me a formula, it would be better

Comment: If I knew a formula I'd put it in an answer. I suspect there's not a nice one. If you edit the question to explain why you want to know and whether an approximation would be useful perhaps someone here can help you.

Comment: Well,thank you for your answer.

Comment: I recently found out that that no formula exists for it.